# Are the names such as $N_1$-space, $N_2$-space used for various countability axioms?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, terminology, second-countable, first-countable

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303436/motivation-for-separation-axioms) the OP mentioned *"$N_i$-hierarchy* for various countability axioms and also that the name *$N_2$-space* or *$N_2$-property* is used for second countable space.

I did not encounter this terminology before and a quick search in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22n2+space%22+%22second+countable%22), [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?q=%22n2+space%22+%22second+countable%22) and [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22n2+space%22+%22second+countable%22) did not reveal many resources where something like this appear. (Well, I expect this post to appear soon among the results of the Google search.)

**Question:** Is this terminology commonly used? Or was is used in the past? Do you know any references where it is used? What are other properties in this "$N_i$-hierarchy"?

---

Added later: In [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708119/prove-topological-space-has-countable-basis?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment5247430_1708119) a user mentioned that they have heard this terminology in Italy. Indeed, when I try to search for ["primo numerabile" "n1"](https://www.google.com/search?q="primo+numerabile"+"n1") or ["secondo numerabile" "n2"](https://www.google.com/search?q="secondo+numerabile"+"n2") I get some reasonably looking hits. (However, I do not speak Italian, so I am not able to understand too much more from them, but the top hits seem to be indeed about topology.)

When I tried to search for ["spazio topologico" "n1" "n2" "n3"](https://www.google.com/search?q="spazio+topologico"+"n1"+"n2"+"n3") I found some results which seems to indicate that $N_3$ is used for separable space. For example, among the results was [this text](http://loi.sc.unica.it/tesi/tesiMCabras.pdf), which mentions $N_1$ and $N_2$ for first and second countable spaces and which says: "Spazi $N_3$ Diremo infine che uno spazio topologico $(X,\mathcal T)$ e $N_3$ se soddisfa il terzo assioma di numerabilita: esiste un sottoinsieme $S \subset X$ denso in $X$ e numerabile." Based on Google Translate is seems that this is definition of separable space and also an alternative name *third axiom of countability* is used for such spaces.

Comment: I’ve never seen it (except in that question).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ditto here. And I wonder if there are more than $N_1$ for presumably first countable and this $N_2$ for second countable. I'd rather use $w(X) = \aleph_0$ and $\chi(X) = \aleph_0$ and have other "countabiliy axioms" be defined by the countable values of other cardinal invariants (pseudo character, tightness, network weight etc.) What would $N_3$ then be, or $N_0$? A hierarchy of 2 isn't much of an hierarchy.

Comment: [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827163/a-neighborhood-basis-in-an-arbitrary-topological-space-for-which-the-inclusion-i) also uses $N_1$ forst first countable.

Comment: The [1975 survey paper by Frank Siwiec](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250130710) "Generalizations of the First Axiom of Countability" has an extensive "dictionary" of defined terminology in Section 1, intended as a convenient reference for the later sections.  Nowhere is a "hierarchy" of such generalizations mentioned in this paper.

Comment: Topic: Topological cardinal functions, which are cardinals associated with a space. Example: The weight $w(S)$ of a space is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that $S$ has a base (basis) of cardinal $k$ or less. (The "or less" matters only when $S$ has a finite base.)

Comment: This seems to be a matter of "local custom". I get a few relevant hits with "axioma de numerabilidad" N1 (spanish), but more with "Abzählbarkeitsaxiom" A1 (german). The latter gives me some textbooks too.