# A neighborhood basis in an arbitrary topological space for which the inclusion is a total order

Tags: general-topology, first-countable

Given a first countable space it is always possible to build a neighborhood basis of a point for which the inclusion is a total order.
Let's say $\lbrace V_n \rbrace _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is any countable neighborhood basis of that point, then define $\lbrace U_n \rbrace _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ as follows:

$U_1=V_1$

$U_k=V_k \cap V_{k-1} \quad \mbox{if $k>1$}$

It's easy to check that $\lbrace U_n \rbrace _{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ equipped with the inclusion relation is a totally ordered set.

Now, if we have a space which is not $N_1$ we may not able to use this inductive construction, so my question is if there is some other technique we can use for a (possible) non-countable neighborhood basis of a point or if it is proven that is not possible to construct such a basis.

Thanks

Comment: How about transfinite induction?

Comment: @sqtrat The problem of transfinite induction is that infinite intersection of open sets need not to be open.

Comment: @Crostul Oh yes, of course. Completely slipped my mind. In that case, I think that this won't be possible.

Comment: A counterexample is $\Bbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology. Any basis of neighbourhoods of $0$ cannot be a totally ordered set.

Comment: @Crostul That seems to be the correct idea.

Comment: @Crostul thanks, I've suspected that if there was some counterexpample it was going to be something with the countable complements topology (since it always provide some counterexample for a propierty related to N1 spaces) but I have to admit I don't realize why is that for any basis of neighborhoods of $0$ it cannot be totally ordered

Comment: @Eliana The point is that no point in the cofinite topology has a countable neighbourhood basis.

Comment: @sqtrat yes, but that's not what I was looking for. What I want to know is if for an arbitrary point, which may have not a countable neighborhood basis it is possible to find a basis (again, I'm not asking it to be countable) for which the inclusion is a total order. Perhaps the fact that a point does not have a countable neighborhood basis implies it, but in that case I can't see how

Comment: @Eliana I see what you mean, I'll have to think about it. I think that one might be able to construct such a chain in case you are willing to invoke the well-ordering theorem on $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @sqtrat actually the reason why I'm interested in finding such a basis is because in the case that basis has the same cardinality of the real numbers, then that basis with the inclusion (regarded as a totally ordered set) would be isomorphic to the reals with its usually order. Then instead of using nets to extend to an arbitrary topological space all those propierties that hold in a N1 space with sequences, we could restrict ourselves to function from $\mathbb{R}$ to the space, if we are dealing with a space whose points have a neig. basis of the same cardinality of the reals...

Comment: ...More in general we could extend all those properties of N1 spaces (those ones which involves sequences) using functions from one ordinal (regarded as a totally ordered set) to the topological space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41222/discussion-between-sqtrat-and-eliana).

Comment: Related MO post: [An example of a regular but not well-based topological space](http://mathoverflow.net/q/240341).

Comment: What do you mean by $N_1$?